# How to conditionally add Custom Post Type to Front Page

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, loop, query, frontpage

I am using the following code to show my custom post types on my front page along with the default post type:

```
// allows the products to show up on the main page
function add_custom_post_type_to_query( $query ) {
    if ( ! is_admin()  &&  $query->is_main_query() ) {
       if ( $query->is_date() ||  $query->is_home()  ) {

           $query->set( 'post_type', array('post', 'product') );

       }
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'add_custom_post_type_to_query' );
```

How would I modify this code to only show/add custom post types of `product` where the custom field called `show_on_front_page`  which is a boolean (ACF checkbox) is set to true (checked)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that if all your products have the custom meta field `show_on_front_page` with some containing `'1'` and some containing `'0'` or some such, AND your regular posts do not have that field, then something like below should work:

```php
//...
$query->set('post_type', array('post', 'product'));
//add this
        $meta_key = 'show_on_front_page';
        $query->set('meta_query',
                array(
                    'relation' => 'OR',
                    array(
                        'key' => $meta_key,
                        'value' => '1',
                        'compare' => '='
                    ),
                    array(
                        'key' => $meta_key,
                        'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
                    )
                )
        );
//...
```

Caveat: If some of the products don't have the meta field set to anything they will show as well.

See https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_meta_query/

Comment: Thank you! That worked perfectly!